# How to query installed packages with specific use flag?

Tags: gentoo

I want to query a installed package, and it must have specified use flag:

> e.g. eix -I curl:*use flag*

Currently I am using `grep` to filter the output. I want to know if it is possible to do it in one command line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use `eix`, you can use its `--installed-with-use` option:

```
$ eix --installed-with-use ipv6 curl
```

You may omit the last argument to enumerate all of the query results for any installed package with a particular useflag:

```
$ eix --installed-with-use ipv6
```

If you need to check if a particular package is installed with a particular useflag and can use `eix`, then you could do:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ! eix -q --installed-with-use ipv6 net-misc/curl; then
    echo "Our distribution server only has an IPv6 address. Please reinstall net-misc/curl with USE=ipv6." >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `q` utility like following:

```
q use +flag
```

Or it's alias `quse`:

```
quse +flag
```

To do this you need to have the `portage-utils` package installed.

Comment: unfortunately, `quse` does not help me filter the packages that are currently installed. so, i am going with @binki 's answer. thanks :)

Comment: You're right, his answer is better. I also didn't know `eix --installed-with-use` so thanks for that